# How to get genres of songs using spotify API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to create a dataset of all my saved tracks on spotify with its metadata. I've gotten all of the song features, the track name and track id. I want to add a column of the track's artist and one of the genre.

I tried adding it by the "liked_tracks.extend" but i couldn't get it to work.

```
cid =""
secret = ""
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback'

FEATURE_KEYS = ['danceability', 'energy', 'key', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'acousticness', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence', 'tempo']

OFFSET=0
SAVED_TRACKS_LIMIT=50
FEATURE_LIMIT = 100

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cid,
                                               client_secret=secret,
                                               redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                               scope="user-library-read"))

liked_tracks = list()
print(liked_tracks)

while(True):
    paged_tracks = sp.current_user_saved_tracks(offset=OFFSET, limit=SAVED_TRACKS_LIMIT)
    liked_tracks.extend([{'name':el['track']['name'],
                          'id':el['track']['id']} for el in paged_tracks['items']])
    print(f'Fetched {len(liked_tracks)} tracks')
    OFFSET+=SAVED_TRACKS_LIMIT
    if paged_tracks['next'] is None:
        break

def get_windowed_track_ids(liked_tracks, limit):
    for i in range(0, len(liked_tracks), limit):
        track_window = liked_tracks[i:i + limit]
        yield track_window, [t['id'] for t in track_window]

track_feature_list = list()
print('')

for track_window, track_window_ids in get_windowed_track_ids(liked_tracks, FEATURE_LIMIT):
    track_features = sp.audio_features(tracks=track_window_ids)
    for index, _track in enumerate(track_window):
        _track.update({k:v for k,v in track_features[index].items() if k in FEATURE_KEYS})
        track_feature_list.append(_track)
    print(f'Fetched features for {len(track_feature_list)} tracks')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(track_feature_list)
mysavedsongs = f'liked_tracks_{int(time())}.csv'
df.to_csv(mysavedsongs, index=False)
print('')
print(f'Saved features to {mysavedsongs}')
```

Comment: hey i have the same problem as you, did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Neither Spotify nor Spotipy offer `genre` as metadata for a song; however, `genre` is provided as metadata for an artist. You could use the song and the search API to retrieve data about the artist; you could extract the metadata here to get the genre of the artist. This will not always be perfect, but is likely the best option exclusively using Spotipy or the Spotify API:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

song_name = 'Sicko Mode'
artist_name = 'Drake' #optional

# hit search API
results = sp.search(q=f'track:{song_name} artist:{artist_name}', type='track', limit=1)

if results['tracks']['items']:
    # gets artist
    artist_id = results['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['id']
    
    # gets artist metadata
    artist_info = sp.artist(artist_id)
    
    # extracts genre
    genres = artist_info['genres']
    print(f"Genres for {artist_name}: {', '.join(genres)}")
else:
    print("Song not found.")
```